# Emberjs - unable to redefine named, explicitly compiled Handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

As part of an attempt to port a fairly large/complex existing application to the Ember world, I'm generating and compiling named Handlebars templates dynamically, and associating views with them, using the technique:

```
var template = Ember.Handlebars.compile("some handlebars stuff");
Ember.TEMPLATES["myTemplate"] = template;

var view = Ember.View.create({
  templateName: "myTemplate"
});
```

One of the things I'd like to do is be able to recompile new/different Handlebars template markup which overwrites the template named "myTemplate" and have it be accessible to views at that name.

I'm getting unexpected results trying to do this - a couple fiddles that illustrate the problems:

[First fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxJw5/13/) - Shows what happens if you wait before rendering a view after the named template contents have changed.

[Second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XTXCV/1/) - Shows what happens if there's no delay before rendering a view after the named template contents have changed.

There's obviously some magic under the hood that I'm not understanding. Can anyone shed some light on this?

**UPDATE:**

I went through the source code for Ember.View and the container module, and came to realize that I could solve the problem in the First fiddle by overriding the "template" computed property in a way that skips the container cache lookup. I've put up another [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xxp4e/10/) to demonstrate the solution I found.

This seems to be working the way I'd like it to - but - it feels like I might be fighting with the framework and "unhooking" from the container in a way that might bite me later. Is there a better, more Ember-esque way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Will the hack I found break things?

**UPDATE 2**

I've also discovered that it's also possible to simply call

```
view2.get('container').reset();
```

before appending view2 in the First fiddle. Seems cleaner/safer, but is it "legal"? I've updated the [First fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxJw5/15/) to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to call this one answered. As I mentioned in my second comment, I'm using the solution shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephenrs/fxJw5/17/) in my project, along these lines:

```
mYiew.get('container').reset();
```

There's some discussion about the container not being intended to be used as an API here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/5becdc4467573f80a5c5dbb51d97c6b9239714a8 , but there doesn't seem to be any mention of using the container from Views for other use cases.

Also, a View's container can be accessed directly (at ".container") - meaning the devs haven't made it "hard" to get to the way they have for an Application's ".__ container __". This might suggest something about how they intend it to be used.

Since a View having the ability to clear its cache whenever it wants to doesn't seem to me to be unreasonable or a bad practice, I'm using the above mentioned solution...at least until someone sets me straight with a better idea (or a cache API).

Answer (score 0):

*(in the second fiddle, both views show the second template)*

This is because `view1.appendTo($("#target"));` just schedules the append, actual view rendering does not happen until end of the run loop. Before that happens, you've set `Ember.TEMPLATES["myTemplate"] = template2;`

*(in the first fiddle, both views show the first template)*

Pretty sure this is because ember container caches template fx, but not 100% on that. Checking...

Comment: @MikeGrassoti Thanks, the first part of you answer (regarding the second fiddle) makes perfect sense to me...although I'm very new to Ember, and the run loop is still something of a mystery to me. The real problem I'm trying to solve though involves the first fiddle - and although I've begun to realize that views get their templates from something like a call to container.lookup('template'), I haven't been able to find out how the container manages data, and what the caching rules might be. Any further help along these lines would be really great. Thanks again.

Comment: Container is not part of the public api, but if it helps you can see what's going on in js console via `App.__container__` - source code for the container is here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/container/lib/main.js - also FWIW more about the run loop here: http://machty.github.com/blog/2013/01/12/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-the-ember-run-loop/

Comment: Thanks again Mike. I was able to see pretty clearly what's going on by going through the source code (see my updates). I'm just still not sure what the recommended practice is for this sort of thing...which comes with the bleeding edge territory I guess. Also, I read that interacting with the App.container as a public API to access global scope is not recommended , but I haven't seen anything about View.container...and letting views clear their own caches seems like a good idea to me, so I'm currently using the second update solution. Hopefully, someone will chime in with some insight.